# Problem converting tensorflow model to lite version

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I've managed to create a TensorFlow model, saved as SavedModel .pb format with a custom operation.

My problem is that I cannot convert it to lite version either using command line utilities or python API

my python API is:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import os
import custom_op

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./SavedModel")
converter.target_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
                        tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS] 

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

But conversion failed with error:

```
ValueError: Provide an input shape for input array 'X'.
```

I assume because my placeholders don't have a shape type. I don't understand why the normal TensorFlow model works with out it.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it describes in [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_savedmodel_) of TensorFlow Lite, you can pass different parameters in `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model`.

> For more complex SavedModels, the optional parameters that can be passed into `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` are `input_arrays, input_shapes, output_arrays, tag_set and signature_key`. Details of each parameter are available by running `help(tf.lite.TFLiteConverter)`.

You can pass this information as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model). You need to provide input shape for your input array 'X'. Like,

```
tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("./Saved_model", input_shapes={("X" : [1,H,W,C])})
```

Comment: ok thnx

I'll then need to fix my code that creates my model. In there I have:

`# tf Graph Input
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')`

I have to figure out what the shape parameter should be. Anything I've tried so far besides the above code threw an exception